# How to access section from extension method?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods

I'm writing html extension (Razor) for javascript rendered charts.
I can edit javascript to read most values from data attributes, but sometime I need to insert directly inline javascript into the page and link a library. I want to make it automatic.
Is there some way to access a section (like `@RenderSection("Scripts", false)` ) from extension method via html helper?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RenderSection is regular method of WebPageBase so you can use it in your helper. Here you have a snippet:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static HelperResult InvokeRenderSection(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        var view = (WebPageBase)html.ViewDataContainer;
        var result = view.RenderSection("scripts", false);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, but how can I write to section? When I try to call `result.WriteTo()` method, I get `The file "~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderSection" method`.  
It seems there is no way to write to section from html helper method.